# Identity Server - HttpContext.User.Claims not showing all claims when Using add cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, identityserver4, openid-connect, duende-identity-server

I have 2 projects:
Identity Server
and C# Razor Client.

Identity Server is configured to pass some custom claims inside the access token.

```
    IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =
        new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
            };

IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =
    new List<ApiScope>
    {
            new ApiScope("Api.Data",
            "Personal Data submitted by yourself in Your Account",
            new []
            {
                $"{nameof(User)}.{nameof(User.NickName)}",
                $"{nameof(User)}.{nameof(User.Country)}",
                $"{nameof(User)}.{nameof(User.City)}"
            }),
            new ApiScope(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName)
    };

IEnumerable<Client> Clients =
    new List<Client>
    {
            // interactive ASP.NET Core Web App
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "web",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    
                // where to redirect to after login
                RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:7070/signin-oidc" },

                // where to redirect to after logout
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:7070/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName,
                    "Api.Data",
                },
                UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
            }
    };
```

The Web Client is connecting to the identity server as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
     .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:44302";

        options.ClientId = "web";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code";

        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.Scope.Add("IdentityServerApi");
        options.Scope.Add("Api.Data");

        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    });
```

If I open the accessToken inside the cookie manually by doing the following:

```
 var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(accessToken);

            var formatted = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jwtSecurityToken.Payload, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });

            Json = formatted;
```

I can see my custom claims when i do the above, but not in HttpContext.User.Claims.

I would like my custom claims to show up in HttpContext.User.Claims.

I know I can add them as an IdentityResource, but I have a third api which uses the accessToken to retrieve the same details (hence why its in apiScope not IdentityResource).

Also the solution to add both the ApiScope and IdentityResource would work, however it would need maintiaining the lists in sync.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may have to add them inside the OIDC connect events within the client. There's an OnAuthenticationCodeReceived callback in which you can add your custom claims to your auth ticket. You could also do it inside OnTokenResponseReceived and get the claims from the claims principal.